# Parsing string into data type : better error messages?

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc

Currently I am parsing strings into data types using 
the `read` function from `Text.Read` as shown in the 
example below :

```
module Main where

data Inner = Inner { x :: Int , y :: Double } deriving (Read,Show)
data Outer = Outer { inner :: Inner } deriving (Read,Show)

parseOuter :: Outer
parseOuter = read "Outer { inner = Inner { x = 4, y = 4.5 } }"

main = do
  print parseOuter
  --output : Outer {inner = Inner {x = 4, y = 4.5}}
```

However the error messages are not very good. For example if 
I accidentally make `x` a `Double` by doing `x = 4.3` then I 
get the error message shown in the program below :

```
module Main where

data Inner = Inner { x :: Int , y :: Double } deriving (Read,Show)
data Outer = Outer { inner :: Inner } deriving (Read,Show)

parseOuter :: Outer
parseOuter = read "Outer { inner = Inner { x = 4.3 , y = 4.5 } }"

main = do
  print parseOuter
  --output : *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Is there functionality in haskell which would allow me to 
do the above but with better error messages?

Comment: You could look at the [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Text-Read.html#read) of the `read` function and tweak it...

Comment: use a real parser like parsec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a more graceful error handling, you can use

```
import Text.Read

parseOuter :: Maybe Outer
parseOuter = readMaybe "Outer { inner = Inner { x = 4, y = 4.5 } }"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  case parseOther of
    Just x  -> print x
    Nothing -> putStrLn "parse error"
```

For more serious error handling, I'd use a proper parsing library like parsec. Parsec provides the `<?>` operator to decorate the parser with helpful error messages: e.g. `myParser <?> "foo"` will generate messages such as "expected foo" if a parse error occurs.